# python api sdk script to pull all secretes from Thycotic folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for script to retrieve secrets from Thycotic using python sdk API, below script is working with single secrete Id, we want to get all secrets inside folder. We have multiple secrets inside folder hence we want to retrieve all of them.

```
import http.client
import urllib
import json
import requests

site = 'https://server1'
authApi = '/oauth2/token'
api = site + '/api/v1'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

#Authenticate to Secret Server
def getAuthToken(username, password):
    creds = {}
    creds['username'] = username
    creds['password'] = password
    creds['grant_type'] = 'password'

    uri = site + authApi
    headers = {'Accept':'application/json', 'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    resp = requests.post(uri, data=creds, headers=headers)

    if resp.status_code not in (200, 304):
        raise Exception("Problems getting a token from Secret Server for %s. %s %s" % (username, resp.status_code, resp))
    return resp.json()["access_token"]

#REST call to retrieve a secret by ID
def GetSecret(token, secretId):
    headers = {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + token, 'content-type':'application/json'}
    resp = requests.get(api + '/secrets/' + str(secretId), headers=headers)

    if resp.status_code not in (200, 304):
        raise Exception("Error retrieving Secret. %s %s" % (resp.status_code, resp))
    return resp.json()

print("Attempting authentication for %s..." % username)
token = getAuthToken(username, password)
print("Authentication successful.")
print()

#Get secret with ID = 1
print("Retrieving Secret with id: 1...")
secret = GetSecret(token, 1)

print("Secret Name: " + secret['name'])
print("Secret ID: " + str(secret['id']))
```

Comment: https://docs.thycotic.com/ss/10.9.0/api-scripting/rest-api-python3-scripts

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need is the folder ID. Then change this line:

`resp = requests.get(api + '/secrets/' + str(secretId), headers=headers)`

to:

`resp = requests.get(api + '/folders/' + str(<insert-folder-id>), headers=headers)`

getSecret will then return the response body of all items in the folder ID that you pass.